# Loop scanning total row content of a sheet

Tags: excel, for-loop, office-2013, vba

I can't solve the following situation: I have a loop that copies values in a sheet called "`the_collector`".  At the same time all the copied values are sheetsnames that allready exists. So all the copied values in the first column are sheetnames. Lets move to the problem: In the second column I want to know the length of the content of the sheets. I tried this loop:

```
1. Sub Knop1_Klikken()
2.  Sheets.Add.Name = "The_collector"
3.  Sheets("The_collector").Move after:=Sheets("Blad2")
4.  For Count = 1 To 25
5.    snames = Sheets("Blad2").Cells(Count, 1).Value
6.    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(1, 1).Value = "snames"
7.    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(Count, 1).Value = snames
8.    countlastuntillrows = Sheets(Sheets(snames)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
9.    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(Count, 2).Value = countlastuntillrows
10.  Next Count 
11.End Sub
```

sure, when I leave line eight and nine out then I get the list of sheetnames in a sheet. so far so good. When I add the two lines I don't get anything. I think something is wrong with line eight: the `countlastuntillrows` variable. I get error 13 when I do a step for step check. It points out to line eight and I think it is refering to `Sheets(snames)`. I look at the help and I get this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj535012(v=office.15).aspx

---

IamDranger: this code works(`countlastuntillrows = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`) but I still get an error 9: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj543427(v=office.15).aspx
further detail on the error:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264179(v=office.15).aspx

I get this code by running the following code:

```
Sub Knop1_Klikken()
 Sheets.Add.Name = "The_collector"
 Sheets("The_collector").Move after:=Sheets("Blad2")

 For Count = 1 To 25
    snames = Sheets("Blad2").Cells(Count, 1).Value
    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(1, 1).Value = "snames"
    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(Count, 1).Value = snames
        validName = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = snames Then
            validName = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    If validName = False Then
        Debug.Print "Invalid worksheet Name " & snames
    End If

    countlastuntillrows = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'countlastuntillrows = Sheets(Sheets(snames)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Sheets("The_collector").Cells(Count, 2).Value = countlastuntillrows
  Next Count

End Sub
```

Comment: You have forgotten the s in front of your snames variable on this line countlastuntillrows = Sheets(Sheets(names)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. Still it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Subscript out of range error type, which would seem to suggest the Sheet name is not valid. Just to try and isolate the problem, can you try and replace your

```
countlastuntillrows = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

line with

```
    On Error Resume Next
    countlastuntillrows = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

    If err.Number = 9 Then
        err.Clear
        Sheets(snames).Select
        If err.Number = 9 Then
            MsgBox "Subscript out of Range: " & snames
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Then run your macro and confirm whether the msgbox actually pops up with any message?

EDIT: I am not totally clear on all specifics at stake here, but see if this code may fit

```
Sub worksheetsInvetory()
    Dim wsCollector As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim curCell As Range

    Set wsCollector = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.count))

    With wsCollector
        On Error GoTo ERREUR
        .Name = "The_collector"
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Range("A1").Value = "Worksheet name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Worksheet last used row"
        Set curCell = .Range("A2")
    End With

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        curCell.Value = ws.Name
        curCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
        Set curCell = curCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next ws

    Exit Sub

ERREUR:

    MsgBox "The_Collector worksheet already exists"

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't it and it works fine. No problems. I think this code is incorrect Sheets(snames)

Comment: Actually you have one too many Sheets here countlastuntillrows = Sheets(Sheets(snames)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row. Do countlastuntillrows = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row instead

Comment: confirmed! the msgbox pops up and I see the error. I have less then 25 sheets. I have changed the For Count = 1 To 25 to Count = 1 To 7. I still get the message: Subscript out of Range: (without snames).

Comment: If the message box pops up just as "Subscript out of Range: " - then this would suggest snames is an empty string for that occurence of the loop, which wouldn't be valid as a sheet name

Comment: How can I fix this, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how I got all these errors, its because of that there are empty cells in the list. I worked around and came up with this code:

```
lastrow = Sheets("The_collector").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

For rCount = 2 To lastrow
    If Not Sheets("The_collector").Cells(rCount, 1).Value = "" Then
     snames= Sheets("The_collector").Cells(rCount, 1).Value
     Sheets("The_collector").Cells(rCount, 2).Value = Sheets(snames).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
    End If
Next rCount
```